# VB .NET App run very slow on 64bit OS

Tags: vb.net, performance, x86, 64-bit

My Windows Form App is written by VB .NET 3.5, and is configured to build for the "Any CPU" platform.

It work perfectly both on 32bit, and 64bit OS (Windows Server 2008) when loading a small form (about 200 controls).
When loading a large form (about 2000 controls): on 32bit OS, it work perfectly as normal and take about 6-70MB on memory; But on 64bit OS, even if it take as much memory as possible (about 4GB and more), become freezed(not responding) and COULD NOT load this form successfully.

I've also change build configuration to "x64" platform, but the result is same.
(Change to "x86" platform will work for both 32bit and 64bit OS, but I don't want to do this, because of I want to take 64bit OS benefit such as memory space for other heavy process)

What should I do to get it work normally on 64bit OS?

Comment: Can you post related codes (the form loading codes)? Where do you load the data from (e.g. text file, SQL server, or anything else?) ?

Comment: A form with 2000 controls hard to believe...what would you even do with that many...

Comment: @Raptor: There are no additional process on form load event. When debugging on 64bit OS, I can see that it take much time and memory when create a new instance of form. As I mention above, on 32bit OS, it works fine.

Comment: Under Advanced Compiler Options is the Enable Optimizations box checked?

Comment: Not really sure what your experiencing but, generally speaking 32bit uses a min of 12 bytes and 64bit is double that of 24. There's no secret here, but you said something about 4 gig that's awful high...

Comment: @Raptor: My current build configuration is Optimizations enabled. And I've tried to change all projects build config to disable Optimizations, poor me, the result is the same ;(

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR: This form is created by user, and add to my app as a custom control. And I also have the same feeling as you when received this form.
Anyway, does you mean it take 2-times memory consume on 64bit OS compare to 32bit OS? 
Since when my app load this form on 32bit OS, it only take about 60-70MB memory...

Comment: Did you install a x64 version of .NET framework ?

Comment: @VAndrei: Yes, of course. My app is run on Windows Server 2008 R2 (64bits version)

Answer (score 0):

what are you system specs.

if you have a good cpu for developing (1.9ghz) then it's good for the cpu.
if you have under 8-16gb ram for developing then I suggest upgrading ram.

8gb for min for large files and 16 for more apps open etc.

you can get 16gb for around £35 which isn't expensive. if you do want to upgrade ram because you got under 8gb then heres a link: [2x8gb ram desktop ram](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/16GB-2x8GB-DDR3-ECC-RDimm-Memory-Ram-Upgrade-for-HP-Z620-Workstation-1333Mhz/302679945535?epid=695351810&hash=item467921713f:g:jGgAAOSwRbtaSl5J)

Or it's that you need a better operating system as that could be why. The OS you might have may be outdated for the visual studio version. I recoment windows server 2016 as it looks like your running it off a server else get windows 10